# problems with assignment Calendar values

Tags: java, android, calendar

i have such problem:

i have Calendar object in Main activity:

```
public static Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();
```

in my second activity i need to set several alarms, so i did next:

```
for(int i = 0; i < alarmCounter; i++){
Calendar calendar = MainActivity.today;

calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, alarmHours.get(i));
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, alarmMinutes.get(i));
calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

            if (calendar.getTimeInMillis() <= System.currentTimeMillis()) {
                calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 7);
            }
}
```

but when if condition is satisfied and 7 days are added to `calendar`, these 7 days are also added to `MainActivity.today`. Why it happens? How can i solve it?

It's important for me to save values of `MainActivity.today` because i change it's values in another method and it's not always equals current date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a memory pointer problem.

Both `calendar` and `MainActivity.today` are pointing at the same `Calendar` istance.

If you want to keep them separated you can use the [clone()](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html#clone()) method:

```
Calendar calendar = (Calendar)MainActivity.today.clone();
```

Answer (score 1):

You work with your references incorrectly. What you need is to make a brand new object clone not to changes the state of the `MainActivity.today`. Here is how it should look like:

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

public class MainActivity {
    private Calendar calendar;

    public MainActivity() {
        this.calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
    }

    public Calendar getToday() {
        return calendar;
    }
}



public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Calendar calendar = (Calendar) new MainActivity().getToday().clone();

        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 2); //set some dummy values
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 2);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

        if (calendar.getTimeInMillis() <= System.currentTimeMillis()) {
            calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 7);
        }
    }
}
```

Disclaimer: Though this is not the best code style it helps to solve the issue topic starter have faced.

Answer (score 0):

That's how a reference is working. You are basically working on the Calendar instance of MainActivity.
So you don't want to do that. Use it like this

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTime(MainActivity.today.getTime();
```